# What is the meaning of the ?ET param sent by office add ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I get a URL param like

```
?et=PAByACAAdgA9ACIAMQAiAD4APAB0ACAAYQBpAGQAPQAiAFcAQQAyADAAMAAwADAAMAA5ADMANAAiACAAcABpAGQAPQAiADEAYgA0ADEAOQA5ADIAYwAtAGUANgA4AGYALQA0ADkAZgAxAC0AYQA3ADYAMAAtADUAYQAxAGQANgA4ADQAOQBjADQAOABjACIAIABjAGkAZA
```

which decoded looks like

```
<r v="1"><t aid="WA200000934" pid="1b41992c-e68f-49f1-a770-5a1d6849c48c" cid="EA8400A9F8ABA4A8" ts="0" sl="true" et="Free" ad="2021-01-24T16:56:00Z" sd="2021-01-24" te="2022-01-24T16:56:00Z" ss="0" /><d>QZk7iI6GEUx1OMEjCyDBIO5pDvGrnFOlEsEzH5vUt6g=</d></r>
```

What ist the meaning of aid, pid, cid attributes. Is there any documentation ?

Comment: Please provide more details about where and when you see this URL. The `aid` is the asset ID of the add-in in AppSource (formerly the Office Store).

Comment: That´s the param string my Web Server receives once a usere loads the add in. So it must be appended by Excel / Office